# Is there a "appears in all" (set division?) operation built into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Sorry for the simple question, but I didn't know the proper way to word it to get useful results.  I was wondering if there was a function in MySQL that supports a "has all" relationship.  The term that I *think* I'm referring to is set division (when I look up division in the manual pages, I only see precision mathematical division in MySQL).  So, for example, if I had a relation of students and courses, I might want to retrieve a list of courses in which ALL of the students are taking (perhaps, the course ID number appears under each student, or something similar).  Does my question make sense?  I can come up with a different query to get the job done, but it would be really nice if I could simplify it all with a simple built in function, you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't. See [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) for a good round up of approaches. The article is SQL Server centric but the same 2 approaches of `GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT` or double `NOT EXISTS` still work.

For exact relational division (with no remainder) `GROUP_CONCAT` could come in handy though.

Comment: Thanks for the material, you're right in that it's a good read :) Thanks again!