# SQL select trying to combine and filter the results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using a PHP script and MySQL to diplay some values from a table, but I'm really stuck, I have searched around the web but I can't really express my question

My table looks like:

```
Table : Tags

Id  Tag  ArticleID
1    1    100
2    1    200
3    2    90
4    2    100
5    3    100
6    5    90
7    6    90
8    10   100
```

The Id column is the primary key.

So I want to make a Select statement that it will display which `ArticleID`s have used of the tags

Example:

- For Tags: 1 and 2    The `ArticleID` that contains this tags is 100
- For Tags: 1,2 and 3  The `ArticleID` that contains this tags is 100
- For Tags  1 and 5    There are no articles that contain these tags

Any help?

Also is there any way to make combinations with the above statement ?

Example:

- For Tags: 1,3,6 and 5  There are no articles that contain these tags
- BUT For Tags: 1 and 3  The article ID that contains this tags is 100,
- For Tags: 5 and 6  The article ID that contains this tags is 90 etc..

Comment: It sounds like you want the relational algebra operation of division.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541243/is-there-a-appears-in-all-set-division-operation-built-into-mysql  It's not built in to MySQL, but it can be done although it's a bit of a pain.

Comment: I thought to use the relational algebra, but seems too messy
The other way to handle this was through PHP:
1) Execute select for tag1 store values in array1
2) Execute select for tag2 store values in array2
..
Then compare the values in the arrays and accept the matches 
but this solution seems to much "slappy"

Comment: quick question there's no way that you can pass the tags you are looking for and the article id you want matched? you just want to pass the tags and get the info..

Comment: Dear Andres, I am trying to find which articles contain all the input tags

Comment: So, what are your input tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a horrible hack, but this is what I could come up with:

```
<?php
$tags_to_check = array(1,2,3);

mysql_query(
  'select distinct t1.articleid from tags t1 where (
     select count(distinct(tag)) from tags t2 where
       t2.articleid = t1.articleid and
       t2.tag in '. implode(',', $tags_to_check) .')
   )='. count($tags_to_check);
?>
```

for each article, I count how many unique tags it has that are in the given set (1,2,3), if that number is 3, we know the article contains all the requested tags.

Comment: It should. As long as you put the tags in the `$tags_to_check` array.

Comment: Actually, Jomoos' answer is cleaner as it does not use subqueries to achieve the same thing. Recommend using his.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following query will do the work:

For example, to check in 1,2,3, I assume we know the count of Tags:

```
SELECT  ArticleId 
    FROM Tags 
    WHERE Tag IN (1,2,3) 
    GROUP BY ArticleId 
        HAVING COUNT(Tag) = 3
```

Here, we have to retrieve the Tags in 1,2,3. We know that the number of Tags is 3. Since no two rows will have the Tag and ArticleId same, We do the following. We take a list of rows which has any of the tags 1,2,3. We get:

```
Tag ArticleId
 1   100
 1   200
 2   90
 2   100
 3   100
```

Then We Group them based on `ArticleId` and count the `Tag`. If it is 3, then only we retrieve that `ArticleId`.

**EDIT:** (Based on comment by @SteveG)

If Tag and ArticleId is same for two or more rows, then we may use `DISTINCT` to overcome that.

```
SELECT  ArticleId 
    FROM Tags 
    WHERE Tag IN (1,2,3) 
    GROUP BY ArticleId 
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Tag) = 3
```

Comment: This is a nice try, but if tag and article are not unique, it wouldn't always work.. Maybe make it `HAVING COUNT(distinct Tag) = 3` ?

Comment: @StevieG Ya, I assumed that: `Since no two rows will have the Tag and ArticleId same`, and I think that will be the case. Otherwise, only the `Id` will be different for those rows.

Comment: @StevieG Edited the answer with new information. I don't know that I can put `DISTINCT` inside `count`. +1 for the comment

Answer (score -1):

Untested, but I think it's what you're looking for?

```
 SELECT t.ArticleID
 FROM Tags t
 JOIN Tags t2
      ON t2.ArticleID = t.ArticleID
      AND t2.Tag = 2
 WHERE t.Tag = 1;
```

Comment: Whoever marked me down, could you explain why this is wrong? Always good to learn from mistakes! Thanks!